# Положить спецсимвол в БД

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть код:

```
for i in range(int(input('Вопросов будет добавлено: '))):
    qst = input('Вопрос: ')
    cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO questions({n_c}) VALUES ('{qst}')""")
    db.commit()
    cursor.execute(f"""ALTER TABLE answers ADD {qst} STRING NULL""")
    db.commit()
    for i in range(1, 5):
        otv = input(f'Вариант ответа {i}: ')
        cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO answers({qst}) VALUES ("{otv}")""")
        db.commit()
```

Курсор и БД заведомо исправны.
Дело в следующем: Когда в поле вопроса вводится символ не [А-Я][A-Z][0-9] (н.п. "?", ":", ...), возникает  следующая ошибка:

```
cursor.execute(f"""ALTER TABLE answers ADD {qst} STRING NULL""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Насколько я понимаю, проблема именно в символе "?". Как этот момент исправить?

---

P.S. Программа - часть чат-бота; будет использоваться в телеграмм. Насколько возможно "обыграть" момент тем, как это принято в HTML - что-то воде местного quote?

Comment: [SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Всё то же относится и к "кривым" именам. И да - служебные символы следует как бы квотировать.

Comment: Подставлять переменные в строки таким образом категорически нельзя, это же [SQL-инъекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)